# How to place a file on xamarin android device so it is available on the device and the network

Tags: xamarin.android, android-external-storage

I've found out that

```
Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath
```

gives me /storage/emulated/0/Documents, but I can't see this folder on my android device.

[view of device folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ivge.png)

Ideally I want to be able to copy or create a csv file into a folder where it can be 'seen' by the device and the network the device is part of.
How can I create such a folder? Thank you.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with - Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

Comment: This is the folder '/storage/emulated/0/Documents' which is still not visible when I view the device folder tree from my computer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can you open DDMS? If you could , you can find these path in file explorer